# EF Core 2.1. Loading nested entities with joining tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I have these models:

```
public class Transfer
{
    public Article Article { get; set; }
    public Branch BranchFrom { get; set; }
    public Branch BranchTo { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

 public class Article
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

 public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

 public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get a list of all transfers made by a specific user, and load all it's related entities (BranchFrom, BranchTo, Article, User).

In EF 6 I was able to do it easily with this code:

```
_dbContext.Transfer.Include(x=>x.BranchFrom).Include(x=>x.BranchTo).Include(x=>x.Article).Include(x=>x.User).Where(x=>x.User.Id == userId).ToListAsync();
```

Given that in EF Core 2.1 you must define the joining tables I added them as follows:

```
public class TransferUser
{
    public int TransferId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Transfer Transfer { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

 public class TransferArticle
{
    public int TransferId { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Transfer Transfer { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
}

 public class TransferBranchFrom
{
    public int TransferId { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public Transfer Transfer { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}

 public class TransferBranchTo
{
    public int TransferId { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public Transfer Transfer { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
```

And because of that I modified the Transfer model to be like this:

```
public class Transfer
{
    public TransferArticle TransferArticle { get; set; }
    public TransferBranch TransferBranchFrom { get; set; }
    public TransferBranch TransferBranchTo { get; set; }
    public TransferUser TransferUser { get; set; }
}
```

Now I don't know how the query needs to be.

I was doing it like this and it works, but only loads the transfer and the user

```
_dbContext.Transfer.Include(x=>x.TransferUser).Where(x=>x.TransferUser.UserId == userId).ToListAsync();
```

When I add another table then it doesnt work and throws an exception:

```
_dbContext.Transfer.Include(x=>x.TransferUser).Include(x=>x.TransferBranchFrom).Where(x=>x.TransferUser.UserId == userId).ToListAsync();
```

I cannot find any examples on how to load all the entities for this scenario

Comment: What exception, my friend?

Comment: Field 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[SIA.API.Entities.Transfer,System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[SIA.API.Entities.TransferBranchFrom]].Inner' is not defined for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[SIA.API.Entities.Transfer,SIA.API.Entities.TransferBranchFrom]''